# Enter different text in multiple cells in a row based on one cell's value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Totally new to this but need some help. Any advice appreciated. I was wondering if it is possible to write some kind of formula that would automatically fill about 12 cells in a single row based on the value of the 1st cell. Eg:

- If A1=1, then B1=Pass, C1=Fail, D1=Pass, E1=Rejected
- If A1=2, then B1=Pass, C1=Fail, D1=Fail, E1=Rejected
- If A1=3, then B1=Pass, C1=Pass, D1=Pass, E1=Passed etc

Is this do-able?

Thank you guys. In response to your questions....

The initial data can be any number from 1 to 9. Depending on what number I enter in column A (1 to 9) I want to output a specific set of texts in cells B to M. For example...

If A1=1, then B1=Pass, C1=Fail, D1=Pass, E1=Rejected •If A1=2, then B1=Pass, C1=Fail, D1=Fail, E1=Rejected •If A1=3, then B1=Pass, C1=Pass, D1=Pass, E1=Passed etc

A1 can be any number between from 1 to 9. The output in cells B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M would depend on whatever number was entered in cell A1.

I hope this clarifies the query.

Thankyou

---

This is the link to an image of the excel sheet I am working on.... 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAmPY.jpg

If I choose option 1 in cell A14,
then I need B14 to m14 to display what is shown in cells b2 to m2

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify the initial data and the exact desired outcome?

Comment: Is there a pattern to the desired values that you are withholding from us?  What is the range of values for the `A` column?  (Are they always positive integers? How big can they be? 10? 1000?)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing some single formula that fills out all the columns, it's likely you'll need individual formula for each column.

An example might be:

- column A is a sequence of numbers
- column B uses the formula `=IF(MOD(A1,3) = 0,"fizz","")`
- column C uses the formula `=IF(MOD(A1,5) = 0,"buzz","")`
- column D uses the formula `=IF(AND(LEN(B1)=0,LEN(C1)=0),A1,CONCATENATE(B1,C1))`

and you end up with a kind of [Fizz Buzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) solver.

Answer (score 0):

If your `A` values are restricted to small positive integers,
`CHOOSE()` might be your best option.  Its syntax is

```
CHOOSE(index_num, value1, [value2], …)
```

For the data you show, the usage would be

- `B1` → `=CHOOSE(A1, "Pass",     "Pass",     "Pass",   …)`
- `C1` → `=CHOOSE(A1, "Fail",     "Fail",     "Pass",   …)`
- `D1` → `=CHOOSE(A1, "Pass",     "Fail ,     "Pass",   …)`
- `E1` → `=CHOOSE(A1, "Rejected", "Rejected", "Passed", …)`